# Throttle AJAX Request On KeyUp and Paste Events

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

So I am calling an AJAX request on every `keyup` and `paste` event in jQuery on a textbox:

```
 $("#server-label").bind("keyup paste", function() {
     $.ajax()...
 });
```

The problem is this is just too many AJAX requests if the user rapidly presses keys. What is the best way to sort of wait until the users stops typing for a bit (say 500ms) before calling the AJAX request. Basically don't make the AJAX request until no keys or paste events fired for 500ms.

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try using `setTimeout()` and a `timer` var to keep track of it:

```
var t;
$("#server-label").on("keyup paste", function() {
    clearTimeout(t);
    t = setTimeout(function() {
        $.ajax({/*[...]*/});
        //...
    }, 500);
});
```

You can also use throttle or [debounce](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-debounce/) but I don't think it'd be necessary if you wrap your code inside a function object or string to pass to the `setTimeout()` function.

Comment: @Anon downvoter, if you have a problem with my solution feel free to comment what doesn't work so it can be improved.

Comment: This is a good beginning, but this solution means a 500ms latency ;-( You should also compare when the event was "last" fired.

Comment: @ThomasDecaux Yes, this will execute an ajax request at 500ms of idling as requested by the OP. You can adapt this timer to your needs, say 200-300ms. Not sure if I follow what you meant with the "last" fired part - the `clearTimeout` will clear the last queued timeout in case it hasn't been handled yet, or have no side effects otherwise.