# AJAX validation "freezes" in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function checkuser(user) {
        var ret = false;
        $.ajax({ type:'POST', url:'user.php',
            async:false,
            data:{'user':user},
            success:function (data) {
                if (data == 1) ret = true
            } });

        return ret;
    }
```

I use bvalidator to validate fields. It seems to fire this function on every keypress and the user is not able to continue typing before the ajax call is competed. I'm not really sure what to do here.

How could I make the function not be ran more than once every two seconds for example?

Comment: Where/How is the `checkuser()` function used?

Comment: you are setting the `async` property to false, are you sure that's what you want?

Comment: Whoops, misread the question. I hope the new title does it more justice.

Comment: @Marko http://karmela.fsb.hr/~bmauser/bvalidator/documentation.html#serversidevalidation

Comment: @DvirAzulay I'm not sure, I just followed the instructions on the link I just posted. I'll try enabling it.

Comment: @DvirAzulay That fixed it. You should have made an answer. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10457743/throttle-ajax-request-on-keyup-and-paste-events

Comment: @domino: no worries, someone jumped the wagon and also provided some additional code to it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get rid of `async:false` but you also need to modify your code to work asynchronously. The synchronicity is what is causing your UI to 'freeze'.

Maybe you could try setting a timeout that will run 2 seconds after a key is pressed on your input, but if another key is pressed it restarts that timer. So in essence it will only after two seconds of no keystrokes.

```
var validateTimeout;

$('#target').keydown(function() {
  clearTimeout(validateTimeout);
  validateTimeout = setTimeout(function(){checkuser(user);},2000);
});
```

You'll need to update the checkuser ajax call to have a smarter callback to work async:

```
function checkuser(user) {
    $.ajax({ type:'POST', url:'user.php',
        async:false,
        data:{'user':user},
        success:function (data) {
            if(data == 1){
              //something to indicate sucess
            }else{
             //something to indicate failure
            }
        } });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could throttle the call with a throttle plugin:

[jQuery Throttle Plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/)