# onkeyup function JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, dom-events

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Throttle AJAX Request On KeyUp and Paste Events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10457743/throttle-ajax-request-on-keyup-and-paste-events)

Let's say I have an `inputbox` in which I have called ajax function on `onkeyup`. When the user enters any value in the textbox, the value will pass through ajax function and write on image using gd.

But I have problem that when user type 10 characters value in textbox then ajax function call 10 times on `onkeyup` and it takes long time for response to write on image.

How can I call function only one time?

We can do it by calling the function on `onblur` event, but I need to do it without leaving the text box.

I would appreciate any type of help.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this by building in a bit of hysteresis in the form of a `setTimeout` call. This is the typical response to expensive operations that may be repeatedly triggered. When a `keyup` occurs, schedule a timeout for (say) 100ms later. If another `keyup` occurs within that 100ms, cancel the previous timeout and set a new one. When the timeout occurs, do the expensive operation.

For example, if your previous handler looked like this:

```
function handleKeyUp() {
    doThisExpensiveThing();
    doThatExpensiveThing();
    doAnotherExpensiveThing();
}
```

...your new one might look like this:

```
var keyupTimer = 0; // 0 is a safe "no timer" value, setTimeout never returns 0
function handleKeyUp() {
    // Have an outstanding call?
    if (keyupTimer) {
        // Yes, clear it
        clearTimeout(keyupTimer);
    }

    // Set a new call to occur in 100ms
    keyupTimer = setTimeout(doExpensiveStuff, 100);
}

function doExpensiveStuff() {
    // Clear the timer handle so we know we don't have a call pending
    keyupTimer = 0;

    // Do the expensive stuff
    doThisExpensiveThing();
    doThatExpensiveThing();
    doAnotherExpensiveThing();
}
```

Comment: @Jimmy: I think I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader. :-) You should be able to apply the above pretty straight-forwardly.

Answer (score 2):

JS:

```
<script>
var timeout;

function keyUp( value ) {
 clearTimeout( timeout );

 timeout = setTimeout( function() {
  // Ajax code here
 }, 500 );
}
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" onkeyup="keyUp(this.value)" />
```